# Unix uniq utility: What is wrong with this code?

Tags: unix

What I want to accomplish: `print duplicated lines`

This is what uniq man says:

```
SYNOPSIS

uniq [OPTION]... [INPUT [OUTPUT]]

DESCRIPTION

Discard all but one of successive identical lines from INPUT (or stan-
dard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

...

-d, --repeated
  only print duplicate lines
```

This is what I try to execute:

```
root@laptop:/var/www# cat file.tmp 
Foo
Bar
Foo
Baz
Qux
root@laptop:/var/www# cat file.tmp | uniq --repeated
root@laptop:/var/www#
```

So I was waiting for `Foo` in this example but it returns nothing..
What is wrong with this snippet?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It probably belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: @Gabe: I guess so, but it could have arisen in a programming context. `uniq` isn't the sort of thing you usually invoke just for its own sake.

Comment: David: Configuring Apache arises in a programming context all the time (for me, anyways), yet it's clearly off-topic. I'd say the same for most one-liners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uniq` only checks *consecutive* lines against each other. So you can only expect to see something printed if there are two or more `Foo` lines in a row, for example.

If you want to get around that, sort the file first with `sort`.

```
$ sort file.tmp | uniq -d
Foo
```

If you really need to have all the non-consecutive duplicate lines printed in the order they occur in the file, you can use `awk` for that:

```
$ awk '{ if ($0 in lines) print $0; lines[$0]=1; }' file.tmp
```

but for a large file, that may be less efficient than `sort` and `uniq`. (*May* be - I haven't tried.)

Answer (score 2):

cat file.tmp | sort | uniq --repeated

or

sort file.tmp | uniq --repeated

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file.tmp | sort | uniq --repeated
```

the lines needs to be sorted

Comment: This should work, but the `cat` is completely unnecessary. `sort` is quite capable of reading its own input. David Z. has the correct idea.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if you use always cut you don't neet to remember what can read and what can't :-)

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I like to have the `cat` in the beginning for consistency with other commands, but Carl's right that it is, strictly speaking, unnecessary. (@pejuko: there's also the option of shell input redirection, e.g. `sort < file.tmp | uniq -d`, even for commands that can't read files)

Comment: @David: yep, I know this redirection and I'm using it with single commands. with multiple commands a I like the pipes. Well, I think we should stop there now ohterwise ther will be big flame about cut, pipes and redirections and what is the right religion.

Answer (score 1):

`uniq` operates on adjacent lines. what you want is

`cat file.tmp | sort | uniq --repeated`

On OS X, I actually would have

`sort file.tmp | uniq -d`

Comment: -1 for invoking `cat` where it's utterly unnecessary. Either `sort file.tmp` (as you have) or `sort < file.tmp` do the same thing without creating an extra process.

Comment: @Gabe - I was using the same format as OP. Also, you'll see I opted to not use cat in the second example

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this myself, but I think the word "successive" is the key.

This would probably work if you sorted the input before running `uniq` over it.

Something like

```
sort file.tmp | uniq -d
```